# Can't filter list item by Content Type in MS Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am trying to filter items when searching a SharePoint list, via the MS Graph API, where certain custom field values are met, and the content type is not a folder. For example:

`/sites/mysite.sharepoint.com/lists/test/items?&select=name,contentType,webUrl,id&$expand=driveItem,fields&$filter=fields/MyColumn eq 'HelloWorld' and fields/ContentType ne 'Folder'`

I have both the custom field and Content Type indexed, but I still receive:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "Field 'ContentType' cannot be referenced in filter or orderby as it is not indexed. Provide the 'Prefer: HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly' header to allow this, but be warned that such queries may fail on large lists."
    }
}
```

I have used the above Prefer header and that does return data, but seems wrong that I have to supply such a value when the column is indexed. Is there something I am missing with this or is there a compatability problem with the Content Type column within the MS Graph API? If there is, how can I work around it without having to use the Prefer header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the `allowthrottleablequeries` preference to execute this query, so you must provide request headers for this endpoint.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site id}/lists/{list id}/items?$select=name,contentType,webUrl,id&$expand=driveItem,fields&$filter=fields/MyColumn eq 'HelloWorld' and fields/ContentType ne 'Folder'

Prefer: allowthrottleablequeries
```

Comment: Good to know another request header for Graph API. Is there any documentation for this header?

Comment: I've used this and it works, but isn't this the same as Prefer: HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly? I can't find reference to it anywhere in the docs

Comment: Good to know that it works. In fact, I once had the same issue a few years ago and then I found this solution on a GitHub thread. But now I can't find this thread again.